# XPage accessing controls values

Tags: xpages

Accessing controls values, what is the recommended way to use ?

`document.getElementById(...)`  or  `XSP.getElementById(...)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XSP object acts a "wrapper" and would hide implementation details (browser incompatibilities, etc.) for you, therefore I would prefer the use of `XSP.getElementById(...)`:

> The [XSPClientDojo](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Client_Side_JavaScript_Libraries_in_XPages.htm#XSPClientDojo) library defines a global **XSP** object which exposes
>   some JavaScript functions to the XPages runtime. As its name suggests,
>   XSPClientDojo utilizes the **Dojo JavaScript library**, however **other
>   implementations may be developed in the future** (for example, when
>   supporting handheld devices).

Answer (score 1):

`document.getElementById(...)` places the reliance on browser implementation. `XSP.getElementById(...)` places the reliance on the IBM Dojo extension and IBM support.

The same rules hold for any of the `XSP....` methods. If browsers changes should ever affect it, IBM code will be updated and **as long as your server is on the current release and fix packs** you will not need to make changes to your application. So as with relying on any framework, it comes down to whether you are willing to keep the framework up to date to leverage the extra layer of abstraction.

Comment: So what is preferable ? Rely on browsers implementation or on IBM Dojo extension

Comment: As mentioned, it depends on how frequently and aggressively you're willing to update the server. If promptly upgrading, I personally would favour `XSP.getElementById()` for consistency. It's marginal at best.

Comment: I would rely on IBM Dojo extension.  Firefox has a problem with getElementById  compared to IE and Chrome.  Trying to get a radio button value in a non-Xpages web form is making me really miss working in XPages.